# How to use ng zorro Upload model with formGroup

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

In the `ng zorro` `Upload` [model](https://ng.ant.design/components/upload/en#components-upload-demo-basic), a required parameter is `nzAction`. It seems that he will upload the file directly to the server, but I hope to store the file in `fromGroup` (or `FromArray`) first, and finally send it to the server together with other data end.

The parameters in the example are as follows: `nzAction="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"`

```
<nz-upload nzAction="'https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76'"
            [nzHeaders]="{ authorization: 'authorization-text' }" (nzChange)="handleChange($event)">
            <button nz-button>
                <span nz-icon nzType="upload"></span>
                Click to Upload
            </button>
        </nz-upload>
```

There will be some cross-domain related errors:
[image]

---

Even if I put a parameter with a `nzAction="''"` value:

```
<nz-upload nzAction="''"
            [nzHeaders]="{ authorization: 'authorization-text' }" (nzChange)="handleChange($event)">
            <button nz-button>
                <span nz-icon nzType="upload"></span>
                Click to Upload
            </button>
        </nz-upload>
```

It produces an error:

[image]

And how should I use `formGroup`(`ReactiveFormsModule`) to bind the value of the uploaded file?

Answer (score 0):

This is the somewhat "hacky" way that I am doing something similar with the NgZorro File Upload component. I'm using a custom "beforeUpload" request that adds the uploaded file to an array; and then when I'm submitting the form, I append the array of images into the FormData going to the server.

in my component.html

```
<nz-upload
    [nzBeforeUpload]="beforeUpload"
    nzListType="picture-card"
    [nzMultiple]="true"
    [(nzFileList)]="fileList"
    [nzShowButton]="fileList.length < 2">
      <div>
        <i nz-icon nzType="plus"></i>
        Upload
      </div>
</nz-upload>
```

in my component.ts

```
beforeUpload = async (file: NzUploadFile): Promise<boolean> => {
    this.fileList = this.fileList.concat(file);
    return false;
};
```